# Plot Derivative of ODE system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to Plot Derivatives of ODE system.

```
n = 10;
T = 20;
r = 1.4;
A1 = 1;
A2 = 0.01;
RPT = 5;
IC = Table[RandomReal[{$MachineEpsilon, 1}, n], {j, RPT}];
eqns = Table[{x[i]'[t] == 
     x[i][t] (r - 
        A1 x[i][t] - (Sum[A2 x[k][t] Boole[i != k], {k, n}]) ), 
    x[i][0] == IC[[j]]}, {j, RPT}, {i, n}];
vars = Table[x[i][t], {j, RPT}, {i, n}];
vars2 = Table[Derivative[x[i][t], t], {j, RPT}, {i, n}]

sol = Table[NDSolve[eqns[[j]], vars[[j]], {t, 0, T}], {j, RPT}];


Table[Plot[Evaluate[vars[[j]] /. sol[[j, 1]]], {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Automatic], {j, RPT}]
```

The graph of the derivative does not work well.

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[vars2[[j]] /. sol[[j, 1]]], {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Automatic], {j, RPT}]
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Definition of `vars2` is apparently wrong,  `Derivative[x[i][t], t]` just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to separate the components of the solution, for example

```
n = 10;
T = 20;
r = 1.4;
A1 = 1;
A2 = 0.01;
RPT = 5;
IC = Table[RandomReal[{$MachineEpsilon, 1}, n], {j, RPT}];
eqns = Table[{x[j][i]'[t] == 
     x[j][i][t] (r - 
        A1 x[j][i][t] - (Sum[A2 x[j][k][t] Boole[i != k], {k, n}])), 
    x[j][i][0] == IC[[j]]}, {j, RPT}, {i, n}];
vars = Table[x[j][i][t], {j, RPT}, {i, n}];
vars2 = Table[D[x[j][i][t], t], {j, RPT}, {i, n}];

sol = NDSolve[eqns, vars, {t, 0, T}];
sol2 = NDSolve[eqns, vars2, {t, 0, T}];

Table[Plot[Evaluate[vars[[j]] /. sol], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic], {j, RPT}]
Table[Plot[Evaluate[vars2[[j]] /. sol2], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic], {j, RPT}]
```

[image: fig1]